# Global characterization of graphs : an immersed submanifold is the graph of a projection $\circ$ diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $S \subset M \times N$ is an immersed submanifold. Let $\pi_M$ and $\pi_N$ denote the projections from $M \times N$ onto $M$ and $N$ respectively.

I am trying to show that if $\pi_M|_S$ is a diffeomorphism from $S$ onto $M$ then $S$ is the graph of a smooth map $f:M\to N$.

The theorem states that if these conditions hold, we can choose $f=\pi_N \circ (\pi_M|_S)^{-1}$.

This means that $S=\{(x,y):x\in M, y=\pi_N \circ (\pi_M|_S)^{-1}(x)\}$.

I cannot figure out how to show that $S$ is the graph of this function. The $N$ component is clear from the definition of $f$ but how can we ensure that the $M$ component of $S$ is the entire $M$?
I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: The assumption is that the map from $S$ to $M$ defined by $(x, y) \mapsto x$ is a diffeomorphism. It has inverse $x \mapsto (x, y(x))$. Hence $S$ is the graph of $y : M \to N$.